# Groovy replaceAll where replacement contains dollar symbol?

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm using `replaceAll()` in Groovy and getting caught out when the replacement string contains the `$` symbol (which is interpreted as a regexp group reference).

I'm finding I have to do a rather ugly double replacement:

```
def regexpSafeReplacement = replacement.replaceAll(/\$/, '\\\\\\$')
replaced = ("foo" =~ /foo/).replaceAll(regexpSafeReplacement)
```

Where:

```
replacement = "$bar"
```

And desired result is:

```
replaced = "$bar"
```

Is there a better way of performing this replacement without the intermediate step?

Comment: What's your input string, and what output do you expect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it says in the [docs for replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), you can use `Matcher.quoteReplacement`

```
def input = "You must pay %price%"

def price = '$41.98'

input.replaceAll '%price%', java.util.regex.Matcher.quoteReplacement( price )
```

Also note that instead of double quotes in:

```
replacement = "$bar"
```

You want to use single quotes like:

```
replacement = '$bar'
```

As otherwise Groovy will treat it as a template and fail when it can't find the property `bar`

So, for your example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
assert '$bar' == 'foo'.replaceAll( 'foo', Matcher.quoteReplacement( '$bar' ) )
```

Comment: How do you specify the file to do this replacement in?

Answer (score 3):

In gradle files to replace use single quotes and double slash:

```
'\\$bar'
```